# How to get the following result in excel without using MINIFS?

Tags: excel-formula, maxifs

I have data in excel as following

[image: Table with data]

I want to get the following result

[image: Table with expected result]

**Logic:** For A -  value in col 2, where the minimum of col 2 when col 1 is A and col 3 greater than zero. The same result can be easily obtained by using `MINIFS(col 2, col 1, "A", col 3,">0")`, but I need some alternative solution apart from using `MINIFS` and `MAXIFS` as they are not working in my pc.

Comment: I request who are expert in excel, help me on this.

Comment: I found one solution using Aggregate function...
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$2:$B$13/(($A$2:$A$13=A)*($C$2:$C$13>0)),1)  ..(for A)


This formula is best alternative for MINIFS function.

Answer (score 0):

In the image below I have recreated your data. In column F I have recreated the results using MINIFS. In column G I have imitated the the MINIFS using an array formula.

The formula in F2 is `=MINIFS($B$2:$B$13,$A$2:$A$13,E2,$C$2:$C$13,">0")`.

The formula in G2 is `=MIN(IF( ($A$2:$A$13=E2)*($C$2:$C$13>0),$B$2:$B$13,""))`. When you have typed the formula you need to do Ctrl+Shift+Enter to get the formula to work.

I then just filled it down for G3 and G4.

Use the Evaluate Formula feature if you want to see how it works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: John can you help me on this

[Query. Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810532/how-can-i-generate-activity-map-for-customer-care-executives)