# How can I generate activity map for customer care executives?

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have data of customer care executives which tells about how many calls they have attend from one time another time continuously. I need to find out whether particular executive is either busy or free in a particular period. The timings for the office is 10:00 to 17:00, so I have sliced the time with one hour in each slice from 10:00 to 17:00.

The data that I have would look like as:
[image]

Note:

1. The data given here is some part of original data and we have 20 executives and they have 5 to 10 rows of data. For simplification we have used 3 executives with less than 5 rows for each one.
2. The start timings do not follow any ascending or descending order
3. Please suggest the formulas with out any sorting and filtering on the given data

Required: The result table should give whether particular executive is busy or free in every hour. If he is on call for one minute it should give busy for that entire one hour period

The result should be like:
[image]

The same file is [attached here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gsKswgFYx5wYN3nn57C7Nt9QL2485ixR/view):
[image]

Thanks In Advance!!!

Comment: What formulas or code have you tried? We're happy to help answer questions so that you can learn enough to solve the problem.

Comment: read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Try using the SUMIFS function (it should be in your version of Excel) to sum the call duration for each person for each time interval, and use an IF to show Busy if the SUMIFS returns greater than 1 minute, or Free if it sums to less that 1 minute. If you get stuck, post your attempt.

Comment: @JohnF I have used COUNTIFS, we need to check whether in that particular interval let say 10:00-11:00 does a particular executive on call or not. But I am able to get only if the start time or close time falls in that interval, I am not able to get result if he is on call for multiple periods like Sujeet is on call from 14:00-16:04. For him I am getting busy in 14:00-15:00 and for 16:00-17:00 but getting free for 15:00-16:00.


Please find the updated sheet here [Click Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eyp9xZ7bRC2eKrHt75yaMnIc_DMlRQCX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @PeterT and Foxfire, kindly check the latest sheet and attempts that I made [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eyp9xZ7bRC2eKrHt75yaMnIc_DMlRQCX/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in an extra logical test in your OR function that tests for start times less than the time interval start and end times greater than the time interval end. So in cell G31 your formula should read:

=IF(OR(COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$14,A31,$C$3:$C$14,">0",$D$3:$D$14,">=14:00",$D$3:$D$14,"<15:00"),COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$14,A31,C$3:$C$14,">0",$E$3:$E$14,">=14:00",$E$3:$E$14,"<15:00"),**COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$14,A31,C$3:$C$14,">0",$D$3:$D$14,"<14:00",$E$3:$E$14,">=15:00")**),"Busy","Free")

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohnF.. My problem got solved!!


But I did not understand third COUNTIF function **COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$14,A31,C$3:$C$14,">0",$E$3:$E$14,"<14:00",$E$3:$E$14,">=15:00")** which will return **zero** in every case.

Comment: Good to hear. Sorry that third COUNTIFS is not needed: I think I accidentally left it there from an earlier attempt. I have amended the answer. The main thing was to add the extra COUNTIFS I put in bold.

Comment: Thank you John for the clarification.